# Keras and tensorflow: gradients for a complex custom loss function

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have coded a custom loss function which computes the MSE of the inverse Fourier transform of y_pred and y_true. These y_pred and y_true are both tensors of shape (batch_size,256,256,2) where the 2 channels at the end are the real and imaginary part. I then build a complex tensor with real+j*imag and use that to compute the ifft2.

How can tensorflow compute the gradients for that? The network trains but I have no idea how it can compute the gradients for this loss function and if it is correct.